# hazelcast management center report No master member could be found

Tags: hazelcast

I have a three-nodes cluster. but the management center only shows 2 nodes with the error "No Master member could be found"
the management center log shows the three members correctly

```
Members [3] {
    Member [10.0.0.36]:5701 - d327eb67-36ea-4226-bca3-3efb69818f1b
    Member [10.0.0.37]:5702 - 015c31b1-e7b2-45ac-b6ba-83d968290aa3
    Member [10.0.0.37]:5701 - 28f3a414-5a16-4dcc-b862-ec37897f907e
```

}

how could I found the master node of the cluster? Is there any way can for the management center to refresh the member information?

Comment: What is your Hazelcast cluster member version and your Hazelcast Management Center version? What does your deployment look like, i.e. do you deploy the members on different virtual machines or multiple cluster members in a single virtual machine? Can you also please share the configuration of your cluster members?

Comment: my hazelcast manage center version is 4.0.3. my HZ member version is 4.0.1. I have 3 members in two physical hosts. I am not running it in VM. 2 nodes in the physical host and 1 node in another host. I am kind of confused about the master concept. what is the master concept in HZ? how to detect it? in Management center GUI, how do I know which node is master?

Comment: We don't recommend starting two members in a single host. Master node is the one that is first started. Can you please share the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: The error is displayed in the web console. also if the cluster side master changed, will this information update to the management center?

Comment: Yes, the master is also updated in Management Center, as we continuously get the new state of the cluster in Management Center. There's no way to get the master member in Management Center, but you can get it via the diagnostic logs. See https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/#enabling-diagnostics-logging. You should look for `isMaster` in the diagnostic logs of each member to find out which one is the master.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue with the current info you provided. Can you please share the member configurations and any error logs you might see on either the members or Management Center?